# How to make a nested table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a table named **groups** that lists of each group. Inside of each group, I want to list the groups **courses**. The group `has_many :courses`, and the course `belongs_to :group`. My current attempt does not work, and I have no idea where to go from there

### ***Current Attempt***

**courses_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @courses = Course.find_by(group: :group_id)
    @groups = Group.all
  end
```

---

**index.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= group.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', group %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_group_path(group) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', group, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
      <tr>
      <% if Lesson.exists?(user: current_user, course: course) %>
        <td><%= link_to course.title, edit_lesson_path(Lesson.find_by(user: current_user, course: course)) %></td>
        <% else %>
        <td><%= link_to course.title, new_course_lesson_path(course) %></td>
        <% end %>
        <% if current_user.master? %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_course_path(course) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', course, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% else %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<% if current_user.master? %>
<%= link_to 'New Course', new_course_path %>
<% end %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

### UPDATE

`:group_id` is the groups id for each created course, since the group `has_many :courses` The lesson `belongs_to :course` but that isnt important, as I just want the table, Thanks XP

Comment: What do you mean by not working - are you getting any error messages? In the index method in your controller, where is group_id coming from? You need to show your models, how is Lesson related to the other models?

Comment: done, lesson isnt really important..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, what do you mean it isn't working? Are you getting any error messages? How have you structured you models? Have you created a migration to add group id to courses? What does your routes file look like - are courses nested under groups? If you don't provide this kind of information, its difficult to provide help.

If you look in the logs, you'll get some messages which will direct you to where things are going wrong. Have you tried running

```
Course.find_by(group: :group_id)
```

in a rails console. I suspect you'll find that this line is causing problems. Comment out this line and amend your erb as follows (I've not included all the code, but just to give you an idea). Also its not a good idea to use tables within tables.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= group.title %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <% @group.courses.each do |course| %>
                <tr>
                  <% if Lesson.exists?(user: current_user, course: course) %>
                    <td><%= link_to course.title, edit_lesson_path(Lesson.find_by(user: current_user, course: course)) %></td>
                  <% else %>
                    <td><%= link_to course.title, new_course_lesson_path(course) %></td>
                  <% end %>
```